# The struct member's value is not updating

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask, ethers.js, hardhat

I am trying to make a voting system and I have come up with something but at the moment the vote count is not increasing. Can you check what is wrong? I am beginner and my code is below.

Contract Code

```
struct Candidate {
    uint64 votes;
    string name;
    mapping(address => uint) voteMapping;
    bool flag;
    address add;
  }
  struct Team {
    Candidate[] candidates;
    mapping(uint => Candidate) candidateMapping;
    mapping(address => bool) addressMap;
    string name;
    uint[] cidArr;
    uint token;
    address creator;
    bool flag;
  }
//More code in between
function vote(uint tCid, uint cid) external {
    Team storage t = getTeam(tCid);
    if (t.flag) {
      Candidate storage c = t.candidateMapping[cid];
      if (
        c.flag && c.voteMapping[msg.sender] == 0 && t.addressMap[msg.sender]
      ) {
        c.voteMapping[msg.sender] = 1;
        c.votes++;
        emit VoteDone(true);
      }
    }
    emit VoteDone(false);
  }
  function getCandidateVotes(
    uint tCid,
    uint cid
  ) external view returns (uint256) {
    Team storage t = getTeam(tCid);
    Candidate storage c = t.candidateMapping[cid];
    return c.votes;
  }
```

Whenever I call the getCandidateVotes method, I have always received 1 even after voting multiple times. Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Hi there, I just ran this code in Remix and it is incomplete. Could you please upload the remaining code for clarity to the community? Thanks!

Comment: @XaEk, You can see my github page instead. https://github.com/sauravk000/voting-system-backend/blob/main/contracts/CandidateHandler.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error is arising from this line of code

```
c.flag && c.voteMapping[msg.sender] == 0
```

in the conditional statement here

```
if (t.flag) {
  Candidate storage c = t.candidateMapping[cid];
  if (
    c.flag && c.voteMapping[msg.sender] == 0 && t.addressMap[msg.sender]
  ) {
    c.voteMapping[msg.sender] = 1;
    c.votes++;
    emit VoteDone(true);
  }
}
```

...once you have voted once, `c.voteMapping[msg.sender] != 0`, and subsequently `c.votes++;` isn't executed